# How to dynamically create and attach an element to the dom when a user clicks a button in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, render, createelement

I'm trying to create a vue webapp whereby a shape (e.g a square) is attached to the web page on the spot where a user clicks. But I can't seem to get vue to create the shape and attach it. This is my code, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<template>
    <div class="shapepage" @click="attachShape"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "ShapePage",
    methods: {
        attachShape: (e) => {
            render:  (createElement) => {
                return createElement('div', {
                    style: {
                        width: "100px",
                        height: "100px",
                        background: "red",
                        color: "white",
                        position: "absolute",
                        left: "50",
                        top: "50"
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
body {
    background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1);
}

.shapepage {
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px grey;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the call of `render`? Any error messages?

Comment: I've looked in the debug console but cannot find any errors, i don't know if there is a specific way to debug

Comment: You need to change the way of doing things: If your component is re-rendered you will miss all you've added, as you don't store added component.

Comment: @dimas change it by doing what? could you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , render just like a function that seems like data() ,so I think you can not use in that way,
If my opinion is right , the render function may same like the render in React.js , it will return a VNode Tree, and in default vue(use template expect render), it will make by template and run when the VNode should be refresh
I hope I can help you

Comment: wow, that's useful information. I'll try doing this another way